# BeautifulSoup: Scraping different data sets having same set of attributes in the source code

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using the `BeautifulSoup` module for scraping the total number of followers and total number of tweets from a Twitter account. However, when I tried inspecting the elements of the respective fields on the web page, I found that both the fields are enclosed inside same set of html attributes:

Followers

```
<a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav u-textUserColor" data-nav="followers" href="/IAmJericho/followers" data-original-title="2,469,681 Followers">
          <span class="ProfileNav-label">Followers</span>
          <span class="ProfileNav-value" data-is-compact="true">2.47M</span>
</a>
```

Tweet count

```
    <a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav" data-nav="tweets" tabindex="0" data-original-title="21,769 Tweets">
                <span class="ProfileNav-label">Tweets</span>
                <span class="ProfileNav-value" data-is-compact="true">21.8K</span>
</a>
```

The mining script that I wrote:

```
import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://twitter.com/iamjericho"
r = urllib2.urlopen(link)
src = r.read()
res = BeautifulSoup(src)
followers = ''
for e in res.findAll('span', {'data-is-compact':'true'}):
    followers = e.text

print followers
```

However, since the values of both, the total tweet count and total number of followers are enclosed inside same set of HTML attributes, ie inside a `span` tag with `class = "ProfileNav-value"` and `data-is-compact = "true"`, I only get the results of the total number of followers returned by running the above script.

How could I possibly extract two sets of information enclosed inside similar HTML attributes from BeautifulSoup?

Comment: On a side note scraping sites like twitter is usually against their terms of service. You might be better off using their api.

Comment: @Craicerjack Well, its a general question to be honest. What would one do in a similar situation while scrapping information from a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, one way to achieve it, is to check that `data-is-compact="true"` only appears twice for each piece of data you want to extract, and also you know that `tweets` is first and `followers` second, so you can have a list with those titles in same order and use a `zip` to join them in a tuple to print both at same time, like:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

profile = ['Tweets', 'Followers']

link = "https://twitter.com/iamjericho"
r = urllib2.urlopen(link)
src = r.read()
res = BeautifulSoup(src)
followers = ''
for p, d in zip(profile, res.find_all('span', { 'data-is-compact': "true"})):
    print p, d.text
```

It yields:

```
Tweets 21,8K                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Followers 2,47M
```